# About IBM Connection 4 OAuth

Tags: ibm-connections

I read through IBM connection 4 wiki: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation and try to develop one third party app to access IBM Connections protected data using OAuth. I registered the application like this(http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Registering_an_OAuth_client_with_a_provider_ic40&content=pdcontent.) but I didn't find to how to get this four keys: CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN,TOKEN_SECRET. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you registered your application you provided the key label and token

you just have to print the clientSecret.